# Looking for a theoretical treatment of closed- and open-classes

Tags: reference-request, parts-of-speech, word-classes

The concept of open-class (e.g. English nouns) and closed-class (e.g. English prepositions) word categories seems to be taken as a given in a lot of papers and textbooks. I'm looking for a treatment of the classes, even if it's not the work that originated them. Does anyone have a reference?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding this volume, and the first, introductory chapter was what I was looking for.

- Corver, N., & van Riemsdijk, H. (Eds.). (2013). "Semi-lexical categories : The function of content words and the content of function words."